# How to set Display Name on Device screen of MobileFirst Operations Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Display Name is not shown on Device screen of MobileFirst Operations Console.
I'm using UserLogin adapter which has no difference from the sample.
Also, I've already checked JSON object response as the below in device log(X is just an example for security reason):

Response Content : {"successes":{"UserLogin":{"user":{"id":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","displayName":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","authenticatedAt":1468543841812,"authenticatedBy":"UserLogin","attributes":{}}},"clockSynchronization":{"serverTimeStamp":1468543842630}}}

How can I see Display Name on Device screen of MobileFirst Operations Console?
FYI, I can see User ID there.
* Version Infomation:
cordova 6.2.0
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016062815
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2016070407

In addition, I've already had the below info but I can't find the solution...

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-mfp-server/html/com/ibm/mfp/server/registration/external/model/DeviceData.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not set the display name for the clients.
Please use API "setDeviceDisplayName" to set display name. You can find more information about the API in our documentation.

For Cordova : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#setDeviceDisplayName

For Android : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLClient.html#setDeviceDisplayName%28java.lang.String,%20WLRequestListener%29

For iOS : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/Classes/WLClient.html#//api/name/setDeviceDisplayName:WithCompletionHandler:

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness.  
I could solve it by just adding setDeviceDisplayName method into index.js.

Comment: @Kim1716 can let me know what is the syntax for calling this method? is it like WL.Device.SetDeviceDisplayName("My Device"); or something else?